# Why does mongodb motor not resolve the data correctly?

Tags: mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

I have a huge tornado app that was written in a blocking manner.  I'm trying to convert my db calls to run async.  I'm having lots of issues.

I keep the mongo calls in a top level folder called lib and in the app folder I keep all my views.

The error i'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/staging_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1445, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/staging_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/staging_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/staging_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1017, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/pubgears/app/admin.py", line 179, in get
    notes, start_date, stats, last_updated = self.db_data()
  File "/Users/marcsantiago/pubgears/app/admin.py", line 76, in db_data
    while (yield chain_slugs_updated.fetch_next):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_next'
```

So inside the lib folder I have this method.

```
def get_chains_updated(date):
  slugs = []
  # Chain class can't do aggregate could create a class instance if i want
  cursor = db.chain.aggregate([
    {'$match':{'last_update':{'$gt':date}}}, 
    {'$group':{'_id':{'site':'$site'}, 'total':{'$sum':'$count'}}}
  ])

  while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
    res = yield cursor.next_object()
    slugs.append(res['_id']['site'])

  yield slugs
```

Later I call this method one of my views

```
chain_slugs_updated = yield chaindb.get_chains_updated(yesterday)
slugs = []
#for site in chain_slugs_updated:
while (yield chain_slugs_updated.fetch_next):
  site = chain_slugs_updated.next_object()
  slugs.append('<a href="/admin/sites/settings?slug=%s">%s</a>' % (site, site))
notes.append('<strong>%s</strong> chains have been updated in the past 24 hours (%s).' % (chain_slugs_updated.count(), ', '.join(slugs)))
```

This is what it use to be when I was using pymongo
lib

```
def get_chains_updated(date):
  slugs = []
  # Chain class can't do aggregate could create a class instance if i want
  results = db.chain.aggregate([
    {'$match':{'last_update':{'$gt':date}}}, 
    {'$group':{'_id':{'site':'$site'}, 'total':{'$sum':'$count'}}}
  ])
  for res in results:
    slugs.append(res['_id']['site'])
  return slugs
```

view

```
chain_slugs_updated = chaindb.get_chains_updated(yesterday)
    slugs = []
    for site in chain_slugs_updated:
      slugs.append('<a href="/admin/sites/settings?slug=%s">%s</a>' % (site, site))
    notes.append('<strong>%s</strong> chains have been updated in the past 24 hours (%s).' % (len(chain_slugs_updated), ', '.join(slugs)))
```

I have tons of code I have to translate to get this async working correctly, I would very much appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To return a list of objects from `get_chains_updated`, you must either `return slugs` the list (Python 3) or `raise gen.Return(slugs)` (all Python versions). For more info, see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).